# How do I implement a Search Functionality in my website?

Tags: javascript, php, web, frontend, backend

How do I implement a Search Functionality in my website?
Is this search functionality made from any programming language or any framework?

I want to know the actual work in implementing a search system and not the HTML & CSS because I already know the designing part.

Also don't want to download any prebuilt tools, just wanted to write my own code.

Answer (score -2):

This is a very basic question. However.

You will need a programming language for that purpose (of course JavaScript).

So , to get a search functionality, you first need to index your website. That is, create a list of texts or words/tags of posts or whatever whether in a database (preferred) or in a simple file.

Next, depending upon your backend, create a program that accepts input from frontend and search the query in the indexed file/database.

Return it to frontend (use JavaScript) and show it to user.

Comment: Ok sir. But how to search that item in my file i.e. which javascript method should I use for that.

Comment: Here is the all in one guide you'll need for this
https://medium.com/dev-channel/how-to-add-full-text-search-to-your-website-4e9c80ce2bf4

Comment: In case you want toh learn to do it yourself, this will help you further
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/implement-search-feature-on-a-web-page-in-plain-javascript-adad27e48